# Get character that is right after a specific word in a string?

Tags: java, string

I have a string of text and a specific word that I need to find in the string.  Once I find the next occurence of the word in the string, I need to somehow find the character that directly follows that word.  I tried to use scanner, but it doesn't contain a nextChar() method, and something of that sort would serve the purpose of what I'm trying to do.  What else could I try?  Here's the code I have, but it doesn't do what I want it to do.

```
public void storeChar(String str)  //used to get the char after the seed and store it in the arraylist of chars
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
    seed = wrdSd.getSeed();
    while(sc.hasNext())  //while there are words left to read
    {
        String next = sc.next();

        if(next.equals(seed))  //if the next word of the scanner = the seed
        {
            ch = sc.next().charAt(0);  //gets char at index 0 of the next word
            singleChar.add(ch); //adds the char to the char arraylist
        }   
    }
    sc.close();

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`String#indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) method to determine if the word is in the string.  If it is, use the returned index, add the length of the word, and use that result as an index into the string, by using the `charAt` method.  Be careful that you aren't running off the end of the string.

Comment: Yeah, I'd never have even thought of using Scanner for this -- indexOf makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `IndexOf` method that the `String` class offers.

```
int idx = str.IndexOf(seed);
return str.charAt(idx + seed.Length);
```

This doesn't do any checking obviously, since your string may be found at the very end and the index will point out of bounds. Additionally, if the string is not matched, `-1` will be returned for the index.

Answer (score -1):

If your text is "Hello World", and you want to find what follows the word "Hell" you can use a Regular Expression such as:
"Hell(.)"

Then the first capturing group will be "o", and that's what you wanted.

If you don't know about RE, read this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

And then this for the capturing groups:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html